# Fetch custom field data for a specific blog post

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I want to output the metadata from a custom field in WordPress post.

On [this page if WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) I found the following instruction:

> To fetch meta values use the `get_post_meta()` function:

```
get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);
```

I am trying to do it this way:

```
<?php
get_post_meta(1, 'Currently Reading',true);
?>
```

But nothing gets output in the browser.

What's the proper way to output the content of the custom field?

Comment: with `get_post_meta(1, 'Currently Reading',true);` is the first argument (`1`) an actual reference to a post id?

Comment: Yes – if you're asking about my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is this:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_meta_key', true); ?>
```

On your post or page editor, you can go to "Screen Options" in the top right corner and check the box to display "Custom Fields".  This will allow you to see the meta keys available.  Just copy the name of the meta key into your `get_post_meta` call in the spot above where it says "your_meta_key".  Don't change the `$post->ID` as that is global.

Comment: GREAT! This is just what I've been looking for. Thank you very much, AndyWarren!

Comment: You can always accept an answer I believe.  Just can't upvote.  There's a check mark below the up/down vote to accept an answer.  I'm upvoting your question, that'll help with some rep.

Comment: By any chance... you wouldn't happen to know if there's a way to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055672/include-html-tags-in-custom-fields

Answer (score 0):

Taken from that page linked

```
<?php $meta_values = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single ); ?>
```

so you'd need to access it through the `$meta_values` return object.

Like so:

```
<?php 
print_r($meta_values);

print 'The ID is: ' . $meta_values->ID;
?>
```

Comment: This outputs the following: "The ID is:" – but what I want to be output is the content of a custom field for a unique post.

Comment: @MetalParchment Taken from the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) : "(boolean) (optional) If set to true then the function will return a single result, as a string. If false, or not set, then the function returns an array of the custom fields. This may not be intuitive in the context of serialized arrays. If you fetch a serialized array with this method you want $single to be true to actually get an unserialized array back. If you pass in false, or leave it out, you will have an array of one.
Default: false"

Answer (score 0):

`get_post_meta(1, 'Currently Reading',true);` will only get the values, you need to store it somewhere and output it properly. One way to do this is to store the function return values into a variable like so:

`<?php $custom = get_post_meta( 1, $key, $single ); ?>`

Then you can output it with a `print` or `echo` like so:

`echo $custom;`

Something to note, try using a value `$post_id` for the first argument. This will grab the current post id.

Comment: Urg... this outputs "Array". I want the actual content of the field to be output. Could you explain please?

Comment: try `$custom = get_post_meta( 1, $key, true);` or even easier `$custom = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, true);`

Comment: np! glad i could help. upvote and accept if it's rite..or most rite (i want all the points!!!) :p