# Include HTML tags in custom fields

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have a "currently reading" custom field in my WordPress blog post, and I want to output it wrapped in an HTML tag.

What I tried was this hack:

```
echo "<h1>" . $mycustomfieldcontent . "</h1>";
```

What the client prefers to do is to be able to set the HTML **in the actual custom field**.

What would be the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  Pretty much the same as your previous question, see the screenshots:

Add your Custom Field with HTML in it.
[image]

Then display it with this:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Your Meta Key', true); ?>
```

And the output should be:

[image]

Comment: Or do you mean you want to put HTML in an editor and then output that HTML?

Comment: Yeah, I mean, let the client put `<h1>` or whatever other HTML in the actual field in the editor.

Comment: Updated the answer.  Its the same as your previous question basically.

Comment: Almost perfect, except it does something really weird now: wraps the REST of the content in the html tag I used in the custom field! [As can be seen here:](http://dimwp.securedev.co/) (At the bottom the name of the writer and the "Proudly powered with WordPress".

Comment: Good deal.  I upvoted your question to put you over the 15 points so you can upvote.  You should answer your own question if you figured it out so other people can see what worked.

Answer (score 0):

This also works, in case you're not using 'get_post_meta()'

```
<?php echo html_entity_decode($custom_field_content); ?>
```